# Pass a Model property as a parameter to an Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 app with C# and .NET Framework 4.7.

I'm having troubles trying to pass parameters with `Url.Action`. When I use this:

```
<input type="button" value="@Resources.ProductCreateOmitCaption" 
    onclick='location.href=<%: Url.Action("Index", "ProductionOrder", new { isWizard = @Model.IsWizard}) %>' />
```

I get this:

```
<input type="button" value="Continue" 
    onclick='location.href=<%: Url.Action("Index", "ProductionOrder", new { isWizard =}) %>' />
```

I have also tried:

```
<input type="button" value="@Resources.ProductCreateOmitCaption" 
    onclick="location.href='<%: Url.Action("Index", "ProductionOrder", new { isWizard = @Model.IsWizard}) %>'" />
```

With this another result:

```
<input type="button" value="Continue" 
    onclick="location.href='<%: Url.Action("Index", "ProductionOrder", new { isWizard = False}) %>'" />
```

With the error:

> JavaScript critical error at line 177, column 60 in
>   http://AnotherPC:53827/Products/Create\n\nSCRIPT1015: Unfinished
>   string constant

How can I do it?

By the way I'm using Razor.

Comment: Are you using aspx view or razor view engine?

Comment: You cannot mix razor as aspx code like that - use `@Url.Action("Index", "ProductionOrder", new { isWizard = @Model.IsWizard })`

Comment: Just remove <%: and %>

Comment: @I'm using Razor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag and `@Resources` are pointing to the fact that you are using the Razor view engine. Yet for your URL you are using the aspx one. There should be no mix of the two, so if you use Razor, stick to Razor - aspx markup simply won't be recognized. Thus:

```
<input type="button" value="@Resources.ProductCreateOmitCaption" 
    onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "ProductionOrder", new { isWizard = Model.IsWizard})'" />
```

Comment: Perfect Answer!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="button" value="@Resources.ProductCreateOmitCaption" 
    onclick='location.href = @Url.Action("Index","ProductionOrder")' 
      + '?isWizard='+@Model.IsWizard +'/>'
```

Comment: OP is using razor view.

Comment: @PowerStar did not knew that